# Is there a .RData equivalent for a sf object?

Tags: r, r-sf

This may be an incredibly dumb question, but I have not been able to find an answer despite my best efforts.

I appreciate having data in `sf` format, but I no idea how to save it outside my current R session. And I tend to run into annoying issues when I save my data as a `.shp` or a `.gpkg` when importing back into R.

So, do `sf` objects have a `.RData` equivalent?

While I know this is wrong, I imagine it would look somethin like this...

`st_write(nc, paste0(tempdir(), "/", "nc.sf"))`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why can you not save the data directly with `save(nc, file = "MyAmazingSFData.Rdata")`?

Comment: Have you tried `saveRDS()`?

Comment: @IanCampbell @jay.sf OMG, I knew there was a simple answer I was missing. I guess I assumed that if I saved as an `.RData`, that it would save as a `data.frame` and I would lose my geometry information. `save()` works. I assume `saveRDS` works too. Thank you!